# Memory leak in concurrent program, or just the way it is?

Tags: concurrency, channel, raku

This is a simplified version of a program which has two channels to carry out some operation

```
use v6;

my $length = 512;
my Channel $channel-one .= new;
my Channel $to-mix .= new;
my Channel $mixer = $to-mix.Supply.batch( elems => 2).Channel;

my @promises;
for ^4 {
    $channel-one.send( 1.rand xx $length );
    my $promise = start react whenever $channel-one -> @crew {
        my @new-crew = @crew;
        @new-crew[@new-crew.elems.rand] = 1;
        if ( sum(@new-crew) < $length ) {
          say "Emitting  in thread ", $*THREAD.id, " Best ", sum(@crew)  ;
          $to-mix.send( @new-crew );
        } else {
           say "Found: closing";
           $channel-one.close;
           say "Closed";
        };
    }
    @promises.push: $promise;

}

my $pairs = start react whenever $mixer -> @pair {
    $to-mix.send( @pair.pick ); # To avoid getting it hanged up
    my @new-population =  crossover-frequencies( @pair[0], @pair[1] );
    $channel-one.send( @new-population);
    say "Mixing in ", $*THREAD.id;
};
await @promises;
say "Finished";

# Cross over frequencies
sub crossover-frequencies( @frequencies, @frequencies-prime --> Array ) is export {
    my @pairs = @frequencies Z @frequencies-prime;
    my @new-population =  gather {
        for @pairs -> @pair {
            take @pair.pick;
        }
    };
    return @new-population;
}
```

It uses one channel for performing some operation (here simplified to setting a random element to one) and another for mixing elements taken in pairs. It works and finishes after a while, but for indicated sizes it starts to grow in memory usage until it reaches almost 1GB before ending.

It might be to-mix channel which is growing, but I don't see it as the source of the leak, since it's getting one element from one block, and one from the other; there might be a few left on the channel before finishing, but not so many as to justify the memory hogging. Any other idea?
An additional problem is that it seems to be always using the same thread for "processing", despite the fact that 4 different threads have been started. I don't know if this is related or not.

Comment: OOC, is this using a version of Perl 6 from before or after https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2644 got fixed?

Comment: Probably. I'll upgrade.

Comment: @JJ IWBNI if you reran this to see if the problem has gone away, or you know what the problem is, and if so, delete or close the question or write an answer. (This is one of relatively few Promise related Qs without any answers.)